# resize iframe with object tag inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, object-tag

Title says it all.  I've tried everything, but the contents inside the iframe is consistently reporting the height of the iframe itself.

I've even added a javascript function in the html embedded in the iframe that does the following:

alert($(document).height());

Consistently it shows the height as being 150px, which just so happens to be the size of the iframe on initial load.  I think the problem is that the iframe has an object tag displaying a pdf.  Visually the pdf is obviously taller than the iframe, so I would expect the document height to be set accordingly, but it isn't.

Why is this happening, and how in the world do I get the *actual* height of the contents?  Under what circumstances would this behavior ever be wanted?

Ultimately, what I'm *trying* to do is print the PDF with a header.  I'm calling a print function in the iframe that calls window.print().  What I'm finding is that the print length will be correct for the PDF (print preview will show 3 pages), but the actual display is only showing the iframe.  In other words, the first page of the print preview will show the iframe, but the 2nd and 3rd page will be blank because the iframe isn't that tall, only the embedded PDF is.

My approach was to make the iframe the full height necessary, print, then reset the height to what it needs to be normally.  But the document height in the iframe is consistently being reported as the height of the iframe itself.

I'm using Chrome to test.